# How to handle Promise in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to execute a callback function in nodejs, using expressjs and angular 2 (i don't know if the angular2 part it's relevant).

What I do is:
I have a formular in angular2, with that I send a get request to my API route, then I send the text field in the formular to the URL via get, then I do an MYSQL query to look into a phonebook database, and I'm expecting to get a complete user with his details, from the phonebook.

Formular:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-4">
<h1>Addressbook</h1>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="doSearch($event)">
<input formControlName="searchString" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

First function, doSearch:

```
doSearch(event) {
    let formData = this.searchForm.value;
    var searchString = this.searchForm.value.searchString;

    this.http.get('/phonebook/search/'+searchString, function(req, res){}).subscribe(
    function(response) {
    console.log("Success Response");
    },
    function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
    function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
    );
}
```

This calls to the route sending a parameter, so not so hard.

Now the create router gets into the game:

```
public static create(router: Router, basePath: string) {
    console.log("[SearchRoute::create] Creating routes for /search.");
    // call the function for retrieving the address book results
    router.get(basePath + "/search/:searchString", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log("##  [SearchRoute] Called GET /search.");
    var object = searchUser(req);
    console.log(object);
        });
}
```

And finally, the function searchUser gets called:

```
function searchUser(req: Request) {

    console.log("searchUser Function executed.");

    var searchString = req.params.searchString;

    var query = p_query('SELECT XXXX')
    .then(function (results) {
    console.log("query executed and all okay");
    return (results);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Wooopsi", error);
    });

    console.log("query result: "+query);
}
```

Additionally, I post here the new query function that I build to be able to handle promises (which I don't know if it was the best choice):

```
function p_query(q) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // The Promise constructor should catch any errors thrown on
    // this tick. Alternately, try/catch and reject(err) on catch.
    myMYSQL.db.query(
    q,
    function (error, results) {
    if (error)
    reject(error);
    resolve(results);
    });
    })
};
```

So, what I actually want to do, what's my issue?

I want to send the result of the query back to the client (the angular2 formular), and I was not being able to do it...

So after this really long post, I really appreciate if you read til here, and sorry for the complicated question!

PS: I know i explain myself really bad :(

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: is the promise use is necessary ?

Comment: maybe not in this case, but I have the situation in another functions that i need to do one query that depends on the result of the first query (in the first query, I look for a client ID, and I use that client ID in the second query), and when I put them in the same code block sometimes they get executed simultaneously and the second query fails (because gets executed first), so for this case maybe not, but i would really like to use it

Comment: where is your e.g. res.json(object) in your router definition? Then in your doSearch you have to handle the received data e.g. response.body?

Comment: You can go with recursive callback wrap them all in functions and one function will execute another one after got result ?

Comment: @Myonara i'm a complete noob in nodejs, if you can give me a link that i can read about that object please.

Comment: @BabarBilal yes, probably i should do that and not make my life harder with promises

Comment: Hope my answer will clarify the links and code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [official angular 2 documentation on the http client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data) they propose to put the http logic into a separate service. I've setup it similar to the example just for a search.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers, RequestOptions,URLSearchParams }
          from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { 
    }

    getSearchResult(searchString)  : Observable<any>  {
        return this.http.get('/phonebook/search/'+searchString)
         .map(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }
    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

In your component import the service and do the code snippets:

```
// don't forget to put the service in the app.modul or the component providers!
  constructur(public mySearchService : SearchService) {}

// in your doSearch of your component:
   doSearch(event) {
    let formData = this.searchForm.value;
    var searchString = this.searchForm.value.searchString;
    mySearchService.getSearchResult(searchString).subscribe(
        data => mylist.data, // or which datastructure I want to write to.
        error => console.error(error) // or how I log the errors..
    );
   }
```

**EDIT:** The search_user in your database model:

```
function searchUser(searchString) {
   console.log("searchUser Function executed.");
   return myMYSQL.db.select('phonebookentry', {
        pbe_lastname: searchString, pbe_syncstate: 'new'
   }) // returning the promise/observable to the main function...
} // Currently I don't know, how the returned data looks like.
```

On the node/express side in [the router](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) send it with [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) **EDIT: use asynchronous call to searchUser**:

```
router.get(basePath + "/search/:searchString", 
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log("##  [SearchRoute] Called GET /search.");
    searchUser(req)
     .then( data => res.json(data);console.log(data) )
     .catch (error => console.log(error));
    });
```

Comment: I added another answer to the post, you helped me a lot, it's only the last function missing! thank you so much

Comment: Second thing that i found:
My component (the angular app) and the service (The one that handles the search) are completely separated things, so the step into the doSearch of importing the service would not work so good, because that mysearchservice it's on the service side... i don't know if i'm explaining it so good

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should go with recursive callback with each query results try to enjoy the beauty of async platform.
Send data to client via

```
res.send(data);
```

Comment: Ok that's a point, i will do it like this. But the question is, how can i send an object back to the client? it's the part that i'm missing

Comment: You can create an empty variable and add data to it after every query and lastly you can send data to client via response instance from your router

Answer (score 0):

Your answer it's completely perfect, i understand everything! The only problem that i'm facing now, its this one:

I'm calling the function searchUser, and it doesn't return anything, just an undefined object, so i quess i'm not doing the return correctly.

That's my searchUser function:

```
function searchUser(searchString) {

console.log("searchUser Function executed.");

myMYSQL.db.select('phonebookentry', {
pbe_lastname: searchString,
pbe_syncstate: 'new'
}).then(function (user) {
console.log("user before: "+user);
return (user);
}).catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
})}
```

Thank you so much for your useful answer! I'm almost finished here

Comment: Oh, the searchUser on the DB-side of node is also asynchronous, I will extend my answer this evening to cover this as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, if you need any further files, or info, or whatever, just ask for it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I've edited my answer and marked with **EDIT**. What I don't know, how the output from your database is looking like in the then/Catch path.